# How to stop displaying long long file list of `ls`?

Tags: linux, putty, ls

There is a big directory which contains 100k files on the remote server, and I typed command: `ls` in my putty.

It starts to display a very long file list, and seems never end.

How to stop it, without closing the putty program?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-C?

Comment: Tried `ctrl-c`,`ctrl-d`,`ctrl-z`, non works.

Comment: Open another session, find PID of `ls` and `kill` it!

Comment: a related good advice is to use `tmux` or `screen` or `dvtm` or `dtach`, to be prepared for cases like these where a window freezes or w/e and you need to control it or do something in parallel in another window ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are over `SSH`, you can use escape sequences.
For example to send break, press:

`enter`, `~` and `B`

"enter" is of course not typed, just press the enter key (I suppose to "reset" the current command buffer)

Other interesting ones

Terminate time-outing session

`enter`, `~` and `.`

Send escape character

`enter`, `~` and `~`

You can list these commands with

`enter`, `~` and `?`

On my system the above prints:

```
# ~?
Supported escape sequences:
  ~.  - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
  ~B  - send a BREAK to the remote system
  ~C  - open a command line
  ~R  - Request rekey (SSH protocol 2 only)
  ~^Z - suspend ssh
  ~#  - list forwarded connections
  ~&  - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
  ~?  - this message
  ~~  - send the escape character by typing it twice
(Note that escapes are only recognized immediately after newline.)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on my CentOS 6. I am using AlphaCom, not putty. But I don't think that should matter.

Answer (score 7):

You can control the ls output by using `less` or `more` command, like below:

```
ls | more
ls | less
```

They'll work on interactive way. Or you can truncate output with head or tail command, like:

```
ls | head
ls | tail
```

head will show default 10 lines from head and tail will show default 10 lines from tail.

Comment: another fun thing: `vim /path/to/dir` (assuming `vim` is installed)

Comment: ya, that could an way too! ;-)

Comment: Can `ls` be smart apply `ls | more` if output length is over 200, and do `ls | head` if output size if pretty small <20

Comment: Also woks well with `tree`.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the output by pressing Ctrl + C (like it's the case with most programs inside the linux shell).

Edit: Just read that Ctrl + C is not working. I think simply opening a new console using Alt + F2 doesn't work with Putty either. Then just close the putty window and open a new one. With that, you can kill the process.

To read the output I would suggest using ls | less or pipe the output to a file and then read it ( ls > filelist.txt ).

Answer (score 0):

In Putty there is a menu that you can access to sending special commands like `break`

Answer (score -1):

Try switching to UTF-8 if you're using something else, edit /etc/locale.gen commenting out all but the line containing UTF-8 for your location, then run locale-gen to update your system.